# The support directory was not found

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I installed "Android support Repository" in "Extras". But I can not find the folder "support". Please help me:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support library is found in this path,

```
 {SDK path}\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support
```

If the support library exists there then you can just include any support library you want For eg: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` in your app level gradle file.

Comment: but i cant' import "appcompat-v7" in here. Sorry my english is bad